# How to Sort a Generic Instance of Varien_Data_Collection

Tags: php, magento, sorting

In Magento, the `Varien_Data_Collection` class makes provisions for sorting, but it ultimately leaves the work up to the extending class (usually `Varien_Data_Collection_Db`) through the `load` method.

**But has anyone already done the work to make a *generic* instance of `Varien_Data_Collection` sortable?**

By that I mean using some crafty means of PHP's user-sorting functions. Not that I'm lazy, but it seems to be a lot of work to re-invent the wheel if it already exists.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Varien_Data_Collection_Filesystem` has some example code for using usort to sort files and directories. If you have a custom collection class which extends Varien_Data_Collection you could implement your own sort functions very much like the filesytem class does. It applies the sort on the collection load method which ultimately has a callback function to usort using a specified sort order ($collection->setOrder('sort_attribute')). As far as I am aware there are no existing methods to do this, mainly because magento does most sorting on db data which can be achieved through the sql which is much better for performance.

Comment: thanks! That looks like just the thing I need. I appreciate the insight.